# Trouble opening certain emails in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Most emails I am receiving are fine, but recently I am getting an error when trying to open a specific user's email. I can see who it's from, the topic, and the first few words of the message in the list of emails, but no content shows up in the message body pane.

If I double click on the message, in order to bring up a separate window with the email, I get the following message:

> Sorry, we're having trouble opening this item. This could be temporary, but if you see it again you might want to restart Outlook.

I've tried restarting outlook, and also restarting my computer, but to no avail.

I've also tried the instructions [here](http://blog.grimeymedia.com/outlook-sorry-we-are-having-trouble-opening-this-item-this-could-be-temporary/) which suggests some issue with my profile, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: I tried creating a new profile, and using that instead, but that didn't help

Answer (score 3):

So, I found that I didn't have much space left on my disk. I had about 200mb left, and after I cleared up a couple of gb, Outlook magically worked again!

Perhaps useful if anyone finds this happening in the future - it could be to do with disk space.